# Sqlite subquery with IN() clause and column name data

Tags: php, sqlite, casting, subquery

I have two tables:

"songs": song id, title, text, liryc - autors id's e.g. 12 - one author with id 12, or 46,60 - as there are two authors of liryc.

The second one, "authors" is author's table with ids, name, surname.
The thing is to FTS search titles and return: id, title and autor's name in one query:

```
SELECT title,
       (SELECT group_concat(name ||''|| surname, ', ')
        FROM authors
        WHERE id IN (liryc)
       ) AS lirycist
FROM songs
WHERE title MATCH :q
```

Since there is e.g. IN(46,60) written by hand, the result is ok - two names separatet by comma.
But if I use column name - IN(liryc) - and there are tow or more ids e.g 46,60,32 - '46,60,32' as I understend it's passed - there is no result or just one name after thousends of CAST trys. Like:

```
... id IN(CAST(liryc) AS INT)) AS lirycist ...
```

or

```
... id IN(CAST(liryc) AS TEXT,BLOB,VARCHAR,etc...)) AS lirycist ...
```

No luck with PHP function:

```
function sliceit($ids){  
return implode(",",array_map('intval',explode(',', $ids)));  
}

... id IN(sliceit(liryc)) AS lirycist ...
```

or

```
... id IN(CAST(sliceit(liryc) AS ALL_POSIBILLITIES) AS lirycist ...
```

Returns one result or none...

Any advice?

Comment: Please go through the guideline form posting the question. edit it accordingly. Code should be formatted properly

Comment: Ooops. Thank you!

Comment: That's what you get for storing multiple values in a string. You should use a separate table to map between songs and authors.

Comment: There are two tables. One with song and second with authors. The only thing that connects them is authors ids in song table. Comma separated, when there are more, than just one lirycyst... Ju noł... The thing is to split column data, this: '46,60' to '40','60' or 40,60 for example, as readable by IN() clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not easy to pass a value into IN() clause the alternative is to use multiple OR LIKE's.

-- column liryc might be 12 or 23,45,345

```
SELECT title,
   (SELECT group_concat(name ||''|| surname, ', ')
    FROM authors
    WHERE id = liryc 
    OR liryc LIKE '' || id || ',%' 
    OR liryc LIKE '%,'||id||'' 
    OR liryc LIKE '%,'||id||',%'
   ) AS lirycist
FROM songs
WHERE title MATCH :q
```

Or use SQLite alternative for MySQL FIND_IN_SET:
http://www.mobileonly.com/sqlite-equivalent-zu-mysql-find_in_set/

```
SELECT title,
   (SELECT group_concat(name ||''|| surname, ', ')
    FROM authors
    WHERE LIKE('%,'||id||',%',','||liryc||',')
   ) AS lirycist
FROM songs
WHERE title MATCH :q
```

Which seams to be a bit faster (shorter for sure)

```
 ','||liryc||','
```

creates empty "values/strings" at the beginning and the end of the column *liryc* value.